# Can you save sets of KDE Plasma app icons (tray/launcher) and switch between them? If so, how?

Tags: kde, plasma

I want to create seasonal variations of the app icons on my Plasma desktop environment but save the originals for later. Instead of just changing each icon individually, as I know how to do and which would take a long time, is there anything I can do to keep the old ones in a preset, then create a new preset for the seasonal icons?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a workaround. I already have a folder of images in my home directory which I've told KDE to take icons from (these are just my custom ones, but you could just copy the original ones here too to make a set). I copied this and kept the name of all the images the same but made variations of the images.

When you set custom app icons for apps on KDE, it remembers the path to an image until you change it. If you change the image but keep the name and location the same and restart the computer, it will be updated when you boot up again.

**Steps:**

**1.** For all of the apps whose icons you want to change, save a copy of the icon in a folder in your home directory.

**2.** Set all icons to refer to the images in the location of the folder. *If you don't know how to do this, refer to the bottom of this answer.*

**3.** Duplicate this folder somewhere else and modify all of the images inside to your liking.

**4.** When you want to switch out the icons, just move the old image folder out and put the new one in its place, making sure that all image names and the folder name are identical

**5.** Reboot the computer

==== Changing Icons ====

**1.** Right click your application manager/dashboard widget and select "Edit Applications...".

**2.** Find the app you want to change and in the subsequent menu next to the app list, click on the current icon of the app.

**3.** Choose "Other Icons" and then "Browse" to find the source image of your choice. CTRL+S (or your save shortcut) will apply this.